# jQuery Clone table row with selected drop down value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want clone previous row's selected option value to the new raw while cloning new row.

```js
$("#btnAdd").on("click", function() {
  var $tableBody = $('#tbl').find("tbody"),
    $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
    $trNew = $trLast.clone();
  $trLast.after($trNew);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tbl'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Cell3</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add New Row"></button>
```

I'm unable to copy the last row selected drop down list value, any solution or cloning is not the way to do it?

Comment: what if i have multiple drop down list in one row? just checking with you. maybe useful for others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `select` elements value as [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) intentionally doesn't copy dynamic state of `textarea` and `select`

> Note: For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into `textarea` and user selections made to a `select`) is not copied to the cloned elements. When cloning `input` elements, the dynamic state of the element (e.g., user data typed into text `input`s and user selections made to a `checkbox`) is retained in the cloned elements.

*Use*

```
$trNew.find('select').val($trLast.find('select').val());
```

```js
$("#btnAdd").on("click", function() {
  var $tableBody = $('#tbl').find("tbody"),
    $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
    $trNew = $trLast.clone();
  //Set updated value
  $trNew.find('select').val($trLast.find('select').val())
  $trLast.after($trNew);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tbl'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Cell3</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add New Row"></button>
```

---

If case `tr` has multiple select, Value's can be fetched based on `index` of the element.

```
$trNew.find('select').val(function(index, value) {
  return $trLast.find('select').eq(index).val();
});
```

```js
$("#btnAdd").on("click", function() {
  var $tableBody = $('#tbl').find("tbody"),
    $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
    $trNew = $trLast.clone();

  $trNew.find('select').val(function(index, value) {
    return $trLast.find('select').eq(index).val();
  });
  $trLast.after($trNew);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tbl'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Cell3</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="red">Red</option>
          <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add New Row"></button>
```

Comment: what if i have multiple drop down list in one row? just checking with you. maybe useful for others

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `$trNew` elements before appending it.

In your case:

```
$('select', $trNew).val($('select', $trLast).val());
```

Comment: what if i have multiple drop down list in one row? just checking with you. maybe useful for others

Comment: @kanishka I personally use class for that e.g. `$('select.cars')`. You can also use the snippet that Satpal provided.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was

```
$trNew.find('.bootstrap-select').next().remove();
```